# Detecting tap gesture that is not on a UISubView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have three `UIButton` instances: `buttonA`, `buttonB` and `buttonC`. Each button has its own center and occupies a certain size.

I want these buttons to "do something" (i.e. have the `alpha` values change) when the the screen is tapped **anywhere** except for where the buttons are, such that one can pressed the buttons to have their `action`s triggered without "doing this something" happening.

What's the best way to go about this, please?

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you mean? How can the _button_ "do something" when the screen is tapped _elsewhere_? Surely it is the _elsewhere_ that will "do something". If I tap in a random spot, how would we even know _which_ button is supposed to "do something"?

Comment: @matt Hi -- hope this clears it up? Say changing the `alpha` value of the buttons when the background is changed, but keeping the buttons working ...

Comment: You can add tap gesture to your view to [do something]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Get location of touch
    let pos = touches.first?.location(in: self.view)

    if !b.frame.contains(pos) && !b2.frame.contains(pos) && !b3.frame.contains(pos) {
        // Change alpha or do something else
    }
}
```

Where b, b2, and b3 are each of your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This works like any other tap. Just give the "elsewhere" (e.g. the view controller's main view) a UITapGestureRecognizer and respond when the user taps it. It won't be triggered when you tap one of the buttons, because in that case the button will eat the tap.